# Extract Heading with JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, extract

**HTML**

```
<div class="product-description__block">
    <h2 class="product-description__title">Product details of Asus Zenfone C ZC451CG 16GB (White)</h2>
    Asus once again provides gadget hungry users with another quality product, the Asus Zenfone C.<br><br>
```

**Jsoup**

```java
String url = "http://www.lazada.com.my/asus-zenfone-c-zc451cg-16gb-white-2801812.html";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements description = doc.select("h2.product-description__title");
System.out.println("Description :"+description);
```

can anyone help me, this code doesn't provide any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the server requiers a valid `UserAgent` string. Add this to the code:

```
String url = "http://www.lazada.com.my/asus-zenfone-c-zc451cg-16gb-white-2801812.html";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1")
       .get();
Elements description = doc.select("h2.product-description__title");
System.out.println("Description :"+description);
System.out.println("Price is " + doc.select("#pdtprice").text());
```

**Edit**
I've added the price.

Comment: it give output but the price is missing

Comment: String price = doc.select("[class=product-price]").text();
            System.out.println("Price is: " + price);

Comment: What is the EXECT output you want to get?

Comment: basically i want price and the description, when i put the code you give it not give output of price.

Comment: thanks a lot @TDG for helping, can you teach me how you know that? thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help! You can take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678000/jsoup-get-data-from-table-inside-a-table/30680629#30680629 and read my answer there - you have to use the `developer tools` of your browser to get the element's selector. If you have more questions you can post it in SO.

Comment: is it the referer changing based on browser computer?

Comment: No. The browser's type is sent to the server via `USER AGENT`. The referrer is the site that you came from. If I'll add a link to another site in this comment and you will click it, than SO will be the referrer. It is also possible that the referrer is another page on the same site (login page that referres to another page).

Comment: sorry @TDG i need to ask you back, im not understand why the price missing. at first the coding you give is okay. is it something have relation between referrer or user agent

Answer (score 1):

Try `h2.product-description__title`

You can see it in action here: http://try.jsoup.org/~Mkx5qLNvIT2cxUHdNLl9vdTUnYM

Comment: Check the link I posted, it shows an example off the css query working.

Comment: oh but i try with the coding, still no output

Comment: anyone please help me why this coding not give any output

Comment: Damien's code works fine. Edit your question and add your whole code, maybe we can find the problem.